# How to replace URL parts with regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a JSON file with URLs that looks something like this:

```
{
 "a_url": "https://foo.bar.com/x/env_t/xyz?asd=dfg",
 "b_url": "https://foo.bar.com/x/env_t/xyz?asd=dfg",
 "some other property": "blabla",
 "more stuff": "yep",
 "c_url": "https://blabla.com/somethingsomething?maybe=yes"
}
```

In this JSON, I want to look up all URLs that have a specific format, and then replace some parts in it.

In URLs that have the format of the first 2 URLs, I want to replace "foo" by "fooa" and "env_t" by "env_a", so that the output looks like this:

```
{
 "a_url": "https://fooa.bar.com/x/env_a/xyz?asd=dfg",
 "b_url": "https://fooa.bar.com/x/env_a/xyz?asd=dfg",
 "some other property": "blabla",
 "more stuff": "yep",
 "c_url": "https://blabla.com/somethingsomething?maybe=yes"
}
```

I can't figure out how to do this. I came up with this regex:

```
https://foo([a-z]?)\.bar\.com/x/(.+)/.+\"
```

In regex101 this matches my URLs and captures the groups that I'm seeking to replace, but I can't figure out how to do this with Python's `regex.sub()`.

Comment: can't you check for foo and replace with fooa and same for env_t with env_a. Do we need to replace with specific pattern.

Comment: @Manjari good question. The part I want to replace can contain different values. So env_t could basically be a completely random string. The only thing that is fixed, is its location within the URL.

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/o9Or0c

Answer (score -1):

**1. Using regex**

```py
import regex

url = 'https://foo.bar.com/x/env_t/xyz?asd=dfg'
new_url = regex.sub(
    '(env_t)',
    'env_a',
    regex.sub('(foo)', 'fooa', url)
)

print(new_url)
```

output:

```
https://fooa.bar.com/x/env_a/xyz?asd=dfg
```

---

**2. Using `str.replace`**

```py
with open('./your-json-file.json', 'r+') as f:
    content = f.read()
    new_content = content \
        .replace('foo', 'fooa') \
        .replace('env_t', 'env_a')
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(new_content)
    f.truncate()
```

Comment: So you have to nest regexes? Is there no cleaner way? And can this be done on the entire JSON file rather than on one specific URL?

Comment: works as long as there's the words `foo` and `env_t`, if that's what you want. ofc works on json. there's another way you can use `str.replace`.